# Find files where 2 given words occur in

Tags: linux, shell, ack

(How) Can I find files where there are occurrences of 2 words in that same file, say `Peter` and `James`? Is it possible with `ack-grep`?

Comment: I want to find files that have at least one occurence of `Peter` and at least one occurence of `James`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just grep twice:

```
grep -l Peter * | xargs grep -l James
```

The same works with `ack`:

```
ack -l Peter * | xargs ack -l James
```

You can replace the `*` with whatever other file list you might care about, or use `find` to generate a list for you.

Comment: I tried this and it does not seem to work. Btw I'm searching for files in the current directory and want to search in every file in that directory or subdirectory (as `ack-grep` does by default).

Comment: Strange, I used an alias for `ack-grep` and with that alias it returned `xargs: ag: No such file or directory` with `ag` being my `ack-grep` alias. But with using the full name `ack-grep` it did work.

Comment: @Bentley4 - I think you've just found out why aliases aren't always all they're cracked up to be.

Comment: Is there a way to also show the lines where any of these words appear in for those files? When I do `ack-grep -l Peter * | xargs ack-grep James` only the lines are shown in those files where `James` appears in not surprisingly. But `ack-grep Peter * | xargs ack-grep James` does'nt output anything at all.

Comment: Sure, just add another `| xargs grep -n 'James\|Peter'` to the end.

Comment: When I do that however it searches from the root, not from my current directory even when I use ack-grep. Any ideas?

Comment: @Bentley4, that means you have the wrong search path set up in your first command.

Comment: This was the command I was looking for: `ack-grep -l Peter | xargs ack-grep -l James | xargs ack-grep 'Peter|James'`