# Find files where 2 given words occur in and also show lines where words appear

Tags: linux, shell, grep, ack

Suppose I want to find all files in the current directory that have at least one occurence of the name `Peter` and at least one occurence of the name `James`.

I can find a list of those files by doing `ack-grep -l Peter * | xargs ack-grep -l James` as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042580/find-files-where-2-given-words-occur-innot).

**But how can I also show the lines where these words occur?** Simply doing `ack-grep Peter * | xargs ack-grep James` does not return the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ack-grep -l Peter | xargs ack-grep -l James | xargs ack-grep 'Peter|James'
```

Comment: The top answer only shows occurences of `James` while the one at the bottom does not output anything at all.